# How to make base64 image saving faster?

Tags: php, image-processing, html5-canvas

Presently my website allows users to save the canvas image but the issue is that it is taking long time. I am sending the canvas image as base64 to my php which decodes it and saves it as png image on my server. Also, I have read like base64 decoding increases image size by 30%. Is there any better approach which takes lesser time to save the canvas image?

Comment: Why are you base64-encoding it?

Comment: I am doing canvas.toDataURL and sending it to php page which decodes it as base64.

Comment: the slow part is probably the connection from the user to the server, not much you can do about that bit.

Comment: where are your users sending the b64 data from? If they're on a home computer, they're probably stuck with the usual "blazing fast" speed of 40-60k/s uplink that their ISPs are oh-so-generously providing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Can reduce the size of the base64 (therefor the upload time) by specifying jpg as image encoding format :

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);
```

You can go further by reducing the jpeg quality (from 0.0 => bad quality to 1.0 -> good quality).

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck with similar speed issues on one of my project and can't figure out how to solve this and hey Pierre, the solution you gave reduces the imagedata size a lot but in the mean time you'll face problems on the saved image from this data. I had done the same thing and while i try to save the png images with tranparent background, i got unexpected images, some get turned to black. So i stick with not using `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);` and still searching for other alternatives.